# Let A,B be non square matrices, but AB square , prove AB is singular

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be non square matrices.

Assume $A$ is of order $m{\times} n$, $B$ of order $n{\times}m$, where $m>n$.

Prove: $AB$ is a singular matrix.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The dimension of the image of $AB$  cannot exceed the dimension of the image of $A$. [if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$]

Answer (score 1):

Expand $A$ to be an $m\times m$ square matrix, filling new columns with $0$:

$$A' = \pmatrix{A&0_{m\times(m-n)}}$$

Expand $B$ to be an $m\times m$ square matrix, filling new rows with $0$: (or any numbers, doesn't matter)

$$B' = \pmatrix{B\\0_{(m-n)\times m}}$$

The products $AB$ and $A'B'$ are the same:

$$A'B' = AB + 0_{m\times(m-n)}0_{(m-n)\times m} = AB$$

And since $A'$ is singular with some zero columns, $A'B' = AB$ is also singular. One way to see this is to consider the determinant of $AB$,

$$\begin{align*}
\det (AB) &= \det (A'B')\\
&= (\det A')(\det B')\\
&= 0 \det B'\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

i.e. $AB$ is singular.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le \operatorname{rank}(A)$, since the image of $AB$ is contained in the image of $A$. Now $A$ has $n$ columns, so it has rank at most $n$, and
$$\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) \le n < m.$$
So $AB$ is singular (being a $m\times m$ matrix).

(It can also be proven from the fact $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le \operatorname{rank}(B)$).